# How to handle exceptions when loading async in a ModelView?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Ligth. The constructor of a ModelView calls an async function named Load(). This function access to the database and web services, taking time and with potential exceptions.
When an exception is raised within the Load() thread, it is not managed by the main thread, so the user cannot show the error message in the UI thread. It is lost.

Which strategies there are to manage these scenarios?

Do I need to to a catch() and put the error message in a property that then is shown in the UI ?

Comment: A C# constructor can never call a method asynchronously since it cannot be marked with `async` ...

Comment: From the creator of MVVW Light: "I am curious why you consider not awaiting an async call a bad practice. In my opinion, it is not bad as long as you know what that means, that the call will be executed in the background and might return any time. Typically what I do is that I call the async method in the constructor for design time data creation purpose and I don't await it. I just take care of raising the PropertyChanged and CollectionChanged events where needed for the bindings to be updated, and that does the trick." In any case, if it is not the way, could you post your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Because it runs asynchronously, so at the time exception is raised, Main thread already passes that line of code and will ignore it.

You can put try catch inside `Load()` method to capture any exception then display it by using `Dispatch`.